# Perform Google Apps Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am trying to do Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority between my Application Service Account and my organization (on admin.google.com). I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation) guide, about three times, and I cannot know where I miss, it doesn't work. My application is not able to do personification of an user inside the organization.

The response of the API says that:

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "error" : "access_denied",
  "error_description" : "Requested client not authorized."
}
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:268)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at StorageSample.main(StorageSample.java:156)
```

Here is my unique code, for test:

```
 String emailAddress = "zzzzzzzzzzzzz@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
            JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =          JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

            //scopes
            List scopes = new ArrayList();
            scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
            scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA);
            scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPS_READONLY);
            scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE);

            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("valid_path_to_secrets.p12"))
            .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
            .setServiceAccountUser("test@mydomain.com.br") // HERE THE USER I WANT TO PERSONIFICATE
            .build();

            Drive drive = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("Test").build();

            String myName = drive.about().get().execute().getName();
            com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.List files = drive.files().list();
            FileList fileList = files.execute();
            List<com.google.api.services.drive.model.File> xFiles = fileList.getItems();

            System.out.println("here");
            for (com.google.api.services.drive.model.File f : xFiles){
                System.out.println("DEBUG "+f.getOriginalFilename());
                System.out.println(f.getDownloadUrl());
                System.out.println(f.getAlternateLink());
                System.out.println(f.getOwnerNames().get(0));
                System.out.println(f.getFileSize());
            }
        }

        }
```

If I comment the line marked (`setServiceAccountUser("test@mydomain.com.br")`), the application works, but I want to do the personification of this user `test`. That is the intention of this guide provided, to grant access to all users inside `mydomain.com.br`.

In the `Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account` section of the guide of Google, as mentioned, I followed all the steps, with attention on step number `6`: To add the scope on `admin.google.com` under the `Security` section.
(google admin configuration for the app)
[image: Here ir my google admin configuration for the app]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the configuration you made at mydomain.com.br 's admin console ?

Comment: @David Yes sir, here you are the screen shot of the google admin! thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have authorized the client id for 1 Drive scope :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

This scope is stored in Java under the constant `DriveScopes.DRIVE`.

But when you create the credential in your code you ask for 4 scopes :

```
scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA);
scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPS_READONLY);
scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE);
```

I agree that since `DriveScopes.DRIVE` is a scope that includes the other scopes in Drive, it would seem normal that getting an authorization for `DriveScopes.DRIVE` would imply that you get the authorization for all the other Drive scopes.

However it is not the case, and you must specify in the `Security` section **all** the scopes that you plan to use. In your case that would be :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
```

But since all those scopes are already included in `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` you can also simply remove the other scopes from the Java code. That's what I would do :

```
...
List scopes = new ArrayList();
scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
//No other scope

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
...
```